# Issue Scraping with PHP

Tags: php, regex, web-scraping, html-parsing

I am trying to attain a value, but step over other values that change dynamically.

The table section looks as follows:

```
Total      1.18     3.33    $20,000     16.2%
```

The code I am using to find the third value in `preg_match` is:

```
<?php
function get_total(){
$file_string = file_get_contents('url');
preg_match('#Total</td><td>\d\.\d+</td><td>d\.\d+</td><td>$(\d+)</td><td>d+\.\d\%\</td></tr></table><br><span id="ExStockDetailTableF1F2"#',$file_string, $data);

$loss = $data[1];
return $loss;
}
?>
```

Comment: Use an HTML parser and then DOM traversal. Most of the time, that's the easier way for screenscraping.

Comment: Could you give an example input? It's hard to know how to parse the HTML when there's no snippet to look at

Comment: I appreciate it, but the HTML is in my work intranet.  I just changed trying to associate the'\d\.\d+' to '[^<]', and that fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wouldn't it be easier just search for `\$[\d\,]+` since represent third group?